# atom wont open except for when using the command prompt

Tags: python-3.x, ide, atom-editor

Exactly as the title says. Atom IDE will not open through the icons, I have to go to cmd to tell it to open atom.
Anyone know of any reason that this would happen?

Comment: Have you tried righ-clicking the icon and selecting "Open"?

Comment: yep. No errors or anything showing up and nothing in the task manager changes that i can tell